# Importing .asc files from Dropbox using R

Tags: r, dropbox, raster

I have a bunch of .asc raster files that I need to access through Dropbox share links. For some reason I am unable to read the files into R. I have tried the `raster()`, `read.csv()`, and `read.table()` functions, but all return errors. R claims the files don't exist, while the Dropbox share links do in fact contain the .asc files. Any suggestions where I'm going wrong?

```
Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)
```

**My code**

```
library(raster)

# define projection
RD_Proj4 = '+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +towgs84=565.2369,50.0087,465.658,-0.406857330322398,0.350732676542563,-1.8703473836068,4.0812 +no_defs'

# The share link for the Dropbox .asc files
pm10 <- "https://www.dropbox.com/s/vkvbabwcwdk2r3q/conc_pm10_2019.asc?dl=0"
no2 <- "https://www.dropbox.com/s/foq2yufvi3694gt/conc_no2_2019.asc?dl=0"

# Trying to fetch the files from Dropbox
rasterData <- raster(pm10, crs = RD_Proj4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MrFlick pointed out what the right URL is, and with that you can do

```
library(raster)
RD_Proj4 = '+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +towgs84=565.2369,50.0087,465.658,-0.406857330322398,0.350732676542563,-1.8703473836068,4.0812 +no_defs'

pm10 <- "https://www.dropbox.com/s/vkvbabwcwdk2r3q/conc_pm10_2019.asc?dl=1"
r <- raster(pm10, crs=RD_Proj4)
r 

#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 320, 280, 89600  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
#extent     : 0, 280000, 3e+05, 620000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.1561605555556 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.2369,50.0087,465.658,-0.406857330322398,0.350732676542563,-1.8703473836068,4.0812 +units=m +no_defs 
#source     : https://www.dropbox.com/s/vkvbabwcwdk2r3q/conc_pm10_2019.asc?dl=1 
#names      : conc_pm10_2019.asc.dl.1
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that `raster()` can read data from URLs. You will need to download the file first. You can do that with `download.file()`. But note that the `dl=0` part actually doesn't point to the data in the file, it points to the HTML page that you view on dropbox to preview the file. You need to use `dl=1` in the URL to actually download the data. Try

```
pm10 <- "https://www.dropbox.com/s/vkvbabwcwdk2r3q/conc_pm10_2019.asc?dl=1"
download.file(pm10, "pm10.asc")
rasterData <- raster("pm10.asc", crs = RD_Proj4)
```